# How to Run Docker Micro Front-End and Back-End Images on RedHat Server?

Tags: docker, apache, redhat, httpd.conf, podman

My apps have many micro front-end in react and many back end in node. I create Create a Dockerfile to build Docker images for all the micro parts.  How will I run all the micro parts on Linux Server?

I find an example where httpd image is used and  the public html is loaded to the container usr/local/apache2/htdocs.  I don't have html file in my React Micro front-end. I need other suggestion or reference git or link.

I try to create a Dockerfile for Httpd at the root level as below, but the build felt to access the dist.

`FROM httpd:2.4 COPY app/myappfolder/micro-fronEnd1/dist  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ COPY app/myappfolder/micro-fronEnd2/dist  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs`/

for instance under app/myappfolder/micro-fronEnd1/ on the linux server,  I have all part of the micro(node_modules,dist, test,package.json...)

Comment: You will need some way of serving javascript files for a web-browser to run your react frontend. That could be apache or nginx or any one of a number of other webservers.

Comment: yes, I am creation httpd docker image using Dockerfile on redhat server, I don't know how to load the micro-front-end to the httpd container. I try to copy the dist file of each MFE as above but It is not loading. Any more details or helpfull git or link , I will really appreaciate

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to help without understanding exactly what you are trying to do and what you don't understand. You may be better off on a discussion forum rather than stackoverflow

Comment: Ok! Richard.  Thank you